# Bootstrap - Use of different classes depending on the screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<input type="submit" class="form-control">
```

I want to add the `form-control` class only when the screensize is `xs`. Right now `form-control` gets added in all screensizes. How can I make it so that `form-control` class only gets added when screen size is `xs`?

Answer (score 8):

You could use two different inputs like so:

```
<input type="submit" class="form-control hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
<input type="submit" class="hidden-xs">
```

This will hide the form-control when its anything but xs.

Comment: I think in your first input you can grouped your clases as: `class="form-control hidden-lg-md-sm">` but is not necessary, this will be ok: `class="form-control hidden-sm">`

Answer (score 6):

You can use @media 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
For example, to do hide sidebar id tagged div when size screen is less than 768:
@media (here is some true value...)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   #sidebar {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to remove most of the style that form-control adds this way for this specific element. It wouldn't be a bad solution, but a simple show hide on form-control with media queries might not be the best if he'd like to use form-control for something else in the future on xs size. If you go this route I think clearing out the styles on the element you're dealing with would be the best bet.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery is another way to do this by adding/removing the class based on the window width. See [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/width/).

*See working example at Full Screen, then re-size to view the change.

```js
function checkWidth(init) {

  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    $('input').addClass('form-control');
  } else {
    if (!init) {
      $('input').removeClass('form-control');
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkWidth(true);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth(false);
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#loginForm {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #loginForm {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form id="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pw">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Responsive text alignment has been added in Bootstrap V4:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/typography/#text-alignment

For left, right, and center alignment, responsive classes are available that use the same viewport width breakpoints as the grid system.

```
<p class="text-xs-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

Copied.

Answer (score 0):

You should use both .xs and .form-control classes together as below:

```
.form-control.xs {/*Write your declerations.*/}
```

Comment: This could work but it also means he can't use form-control at all on xs size if he sets it to display:none.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using media queries in your CSS. Assuming you're using Bootstrap, you can use the **col-xs** class to target extra small screens. Here's an example:

```html
<input type="submit" class="form-control hidden-xs">
```

In this example, the hidden-xs class will hide the element on screens larger than extra small. If you want to add the form-control class only on extra small screens, you can use a combination of utility classes. Note that hidden-xs is deprecated in Bootstrap 3 and removed in Bootstrap 4. If you are using Bootstrap 4 or later, you may need to use different utility classes for hiding/showing elements based on screen size.

```html
<input type="submit" class="form-control d-block d-sm-none">
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?